# Scala - refer child class in parent (generics)

Tags: scala, generics

I am trying to refer to child class in trait in case of generics. It is probably not possible but I will be glad if someone knows solution for this problem. More info in example below.

```
object TestMain {
  trait A {
    def doSomething(objects: Seq[A]): A // can I put something here instead of A to make it work?
  }
  case class B() extends A {
    override def doSomething(objects: Seq[B]): B = {
      objects.head
    }
  }
  case class C() extends A {
    override def doSomething(objects: Seq[C]): C = {
      objects.head
    }
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    B().doSomething(Seq(B(), B())) //ok
    C().doSomething(Seq(C(), C())) //ok
    B().doSomething(Seq(B(), C())) //I want compile time error
  }
}
```

I want A and B class accept only collections of themselves on compile time to not make checks in each of these classes. Is it possible?

Comment: You would have more luck with a **typeclass** rather than with inheritance. Take a look to [this](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/index.html#how-can-a-method-in-a-superclass-return-a-value-of-the-current-type).

Comment: You could also try `this.type` instead of `A` in the original definition or F-bounded polymorphism. Take a look at [this article](https://tpolecat.github.io/2015/04/29/f-bounds.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated by @user you could use [F-bounded polymorphism](https://tpolecat.github.io/2015/04/29/f-bounds.html) to implement what you want.

Given your example, I applied the F-bounded as:

```
object TestMain {
  trait A[Me <: A[Me]]{
    def doSomething(objects: Seq[Me]): A[Me] // can I put something here instead of A to make it work?
  }
  case class B() extends A[B] {
    override def doSomething(objects: Seq[B]): B = {
      objects.head
    }
  }
  case class C() extends A[C] {
    override def doSomething(objects: Seq[C]): C = {
      objects.head
    }
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    B().doSomething(Seq(B(), B())) //ok
    C().doSomething(Seq(C(), C())) //ok
    B().doSomething(Seq(B(), C())) //now this thrown a compile time error
  }
}
```

Comment: One minor issue - line 3 has to be changed to: 
def doSomething(objects: Seq[Me]): A[Me]

and it worked.
Thank you for help :)

Comment: Right :) I change the answer asap :)